# how to call a actionscript 3 function by javascript?

Tags: actionscript-3

this is my actionscript function code:

```
function sayWhat(){
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
mySound.load(new URLRequest("test.mp3"));
mySound.play();
txt.text = "loaded!";

}
```

and i want to load the function when the user click on the link "LOAD"

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [ExternalInterface.addCallback](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#addCallback%28%29).

And here is an [example](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/638/1/Basics-of-using-the-ExternalInterface/Page1.html)

Comment: yeah i tried it but it didnt do nothing.. can you give me a example with my function?